# is_user_logged_in() not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

`is_user_logged_in()` function not working in WordPress plugin.
Shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `is_user_logged_in()` in
> How can I use the logic in WordPress plugin?

Comment: Where are you using it? In what context? Inside a hook? In the admin, in the front-end?

Comment: // Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
}

Comment: Use plugin main file.

Answer (score 9):

[`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is located in **wp-includes/pluggable.php**. So please include this file in your plugin file and check.

Comment: How need to include to fix the problem? please

Comment: include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');

add this in your plugin file

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if($user->ID != 0 or $user->ID != null) ...
```

Comment: Easiest to implement!

Comment: `is_user_logged_in()` actually does nearly the same thing [under the hood](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2b596377be15e4574f9ab0d2a288cb1ef41c11ab/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1063), but it uses a simpler `$user->exists()` call. Perhaps that's preferable over `$user->ID != 0 or $user->ID != null`?

Comment: This doesn't work within a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are loaded prior to `pluggable.php`, which is where `is_user_logged_in()` is located. Which means the function doesn't exist yet when you're trying to call it. Instead, do this:

```
add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
function ajax_auth_init()
{
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) return;
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It is show Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ajax_auth_init() (previously declared in

Comment: Oh, I thought it was your own function. My bad.

Comment: Why do you need to load it only if the user is logged in?

Comment: Here also show same error add_shortcode('ajax_lgin', 'jeba_get_data_from_settings');
function jeba_get_data_from_settings() {?>
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
     <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
<?php } else { get_template_part('ajax', 'auth'); ?>             
        <a class="login_button" id="show_login" href="">Login</a>
        <a class="login_button" id="show_signup" href="">Signup</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php
}

Comment: Where is `ajax_auth_init()` defined?

Comment: Well doesn't that plugin already initialize its own function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function example_function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        ajax_auth_init();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'example_function');
```

**EDIT:**

`is_user_logged_in()` is a pluggable function and you could get a fatal error if you call it too early.
You can use this function inside your theme files without any additional code. Like:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="/wp-login.php" title="Members Area Login" rel="home">Members Area</a>
<?php } ?>
```

But inside plugin you should wait for wordpress to be loaded.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.