# Wordpress is_user_logged_in() only works for admins and no other Role

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, roles

I made a custom admin bar that is displayed only for logged in users. But I just noticed that with "is_user_logged_in()" function it works only for admins and not contributors or spectators.

The code works for contributors and spectators in specific few pages. I believe it could be because these pages have some code that checks if users are logged in. But I don't know.

Here is my PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php global $current_user; echo home_url() . '/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/'; ?>">My profile</a>
    <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_logout_url() ); ?>"><?php _e('Log out'); ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span>Become a member</span>
    <a href="/wp-login.php">Log in</a>
    <a class="cta-small" href="/register">Get invitation</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

I use Wordpress 5.2.1 and PHP 7.2

Comment: Are you using this logged in function? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/ 

I'm not familiar with if blocks not having curly brackets in PHP...

Comment: following up on my own comment, I see this alternative control structure is valid https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php..  have you tried simply echoing the response from `is_user_logged_in()` - is it throwing an error, or just returning false?

Comment: @TimOgilvy Yes i'm using this function. I don't think the problem could be syntax as it works properly for all admin accounts. Problem is that this function in landing page doesn't recognize Subscribers and Contributors as logged in. Maybe other function could help.

Comment: Yep, looks like you might need to find a different function to identify contributors and subscribers. I note there's also a stack exchange site for wordpress users. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimOgilvy There is not much activity there. I already tried. But thanks.

Comment: That fact that the code works on some pages and not on others pretty much confirms the usual problem with this. `is_user_logged_in()` relies on another function, `wp_get_current_user()` (good one to use btw to check different user roles), and there are known issues with trying to use that function without adhering to a proper order or plugins messing with its functionality. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135667/is-user-logged-in-not-working-in-wordpress-plugin). I personally would try to use `wp_get_current_user()` first to see if that works directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the "WP Fastest Cache" plugin. When turned off error no longer is there.

Comment: Nice! :) but that's the cause, not the solution. How will you solve it, keep cache off or change cache plugin? cheers!

Comment: @Nick Change plugin. There is plenty of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the is_user_logged_in() function behaves strangely on template redirects.

Try to use a different condition, replace the first line with this one:

```
<?php if ( get_current_user_id() != 0 ) : ?>
```